# My site crashes IE 7, where should I start to understand such a thing?

Tags: internet-explorer, crash

I could use a bit of insight! I built a webpage in which I use a fair amount of jquery/flash and other  somewhat hardcore layout tools. It was fine in local testing, works in IE 6 and 7 so I delivered it to the customer, who put it on a server and now it promptly crashes IE 7. (haven't tried IE 6 yet). I don't have any decent debugging tools, but crashing is pretty radical in any case. Any idea if just javascript can do this and how to tell it not to?

The site is hosted at www.functionprojects.com/brightoutcome, Cheers and thanks!

Comment: If it helps I get script errors. Turn up script debugging in your IE and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the errors are pretty bad, but since IE completely crashes, that was the behavior that was new to me. It could be my instance or service pack or whatever so wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your site in Firefox gives me javascript errors, as does running it in IE8. FF equipped with Firebug will lock down the error in FF

```
Error: $("#tabs").tabs is not a function
Source File: http://www.functionprojects.com/brightoutcome/
Line: 28
```

The errors in IE8 look like their coming as a result of flash calls to externalinterface, with a call to

```
document.getElementById("ESAS")
```

Which occurs in an anonymous function block that looks like:

```
try { document.getElementById("ESAS").SetReturnValue(__flash__toXML(amGetZoom(undefined,"02-10-2009","05-04-2009",undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined)) ); } catch (e) { document.getElementById("ESAS").SetReturnValue("<undefined/>"); }
```

Sometimes, externalinterface needs to wait a little while before trying to communicate with the DOM as the DOM may not be fully loaded before Flash kicks in.

Anyway, you'll need to fix all these errors.

Comment: Fantastic, I will fix them, and was aware of them, although still not sure why such errors would 'crash' a browser, this is pretty new to me, thats why the sheer panic, I never knew you could reap that kind of havoc even with bad code.

Comment: Oh, and to say it works fine locally, its something to do with permissions on the server and the jquery-ui tab code for certain.

Answer (score 1):

If you run iexplore.exe in a [debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), then [load public symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx) and then dump the stack with the k1000 command, you can at least get an idea from the function names where things are going horribly wrong.  If you paste it here, we may be able to help more specifically.

Otherwise, you just have to start commenting out your script / JQuery until it stops crashing, and then narrow it down to something more specific.

Or provide a link to an example page that crashes for us to test.

Comment: So in your case, it did not crash? I actually took out all the code piece by piece, and it kept crashing, so perhaps something leaves IE unstable? I'm restarting now to see if it changes things. This runs fine locally so I don't know if the debugger would work?

Comment: Are you running the latest versions of Flash and other addons?